# How to overwrite the dots in a ruby range?

Tags: ruby, range

Is there any possibility to overwrite the dots in a ruby range?. My aim is, to manipulate the given objects before the range is created.

I thought of something like this

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support'

#actual i have to call explicitly .to_date
Date.today.to_date..1.month.since.to_date

#this should give me a range with Date objects
Date.today..1.month.since
```

I have already tried to overwrite the initialize method of the class Range. But this hasn't worked as expected.

Comment: You really only have to specify it on second argument since that is the one that isn't a Date object. `Date.today..1.month.from_now.to_date`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had a look at the MRI 1.8.7 source and found a bit of a surprise.  Long story short, you can override `Range.initialize`, but Ruby doesn't call `Range.initialize` when initializing a range created with the `..` or `...` operator.  I can't see any obvious reason it was done that way.  Speed, if I had to guess.

Comment: Sooo what do you have to do to override .. and  ... ?

Comment: @fatuhoku I do not think you can override `..` and `...`.

Comment: Okay, what a shame. I started a separate question for this anyway — just in case.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40380603/how-can-i-override-the-and-operators-of-ruby-ranges-to-accept-floatinfi

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you want to overwrite the `..` is that a strict requirement or you just want to?

The following gives you an array of date objects in the range.  It might not handle all of the cases and requires tweaking.  I don't know why you'd be opposed to pursuing something like this though.

```
require 'active_support'

def daterange(datestart,dateend)
datearray = []
myrange = (datestart.to_date - dateend.to_date).to_i.abs

myrange.times do |x|
  datearray << datestart + x.day
end

datearray

end


puts daterange(Date.today,1.month.since)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the behaviour of `Range.new` by redefining `initialize` but this will not affect the range literal:

```
class Range
    alias_method :orig_init, :initialize
    def initialize(b, e, *args)
        orig_init(b * 10, e * 10, *args)
    end
end

Range.new(1, 2) #=> 10..20

1..2 #=> 1..2
```