# How can I override the .. and ... operators of Ruby Ranges to accept Float::INFINITY?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I want to override the `..` and `...` operators in Ruby's `Range`.

Reason is, I'm working with infinite date ranges in the database. If you pull an `infinty` datetime out of Postgres, you get a `Float::INFINITY` in Ruby.

The problem with this is, I cannot use `Float::INFINITY` as the end of a range:

```
Date.today...Float::INFINITY
=> Wed, 02 Nov 2016...Infinity 

DateTime.now...Float::INFINITY
# ArgumentError: bad value for range

Time.now...Float::INFINITY
# ArgumentError: bad value for range
```

... yet I use `..` and `...` syntax quite often in my code.

To even be able to construct the range, you need to use  `DateTime::Infinity.new` instead:

```
Date.today...DateTime::Infinity.new
=> Wed, 02 Nov 2016...#<Date::Infinity:0x007fd82348c698 @d=1> 

DateTime.now...DateTime::Infinity.new
=> Wed, 02 Nov 2016 12:57:07 +0000...#<Date::Infinity:0x007fd82348c698 @d=1> 

Time.now...DateTime::Infinity.new
=> 2016-11-02 12:57:33 +0000...#<Date::Infinity:0x007fd82348c698 @d=1>
```

But I would need to do the the `Float::INFINITY` -> `DateTime::Infinity.new` conversion every time:

`model.start_time...convert_infinity(model.end_time)`

Is there a way I can override the `..` and `...` operators so that I can incorporate the conversion function and keep the syntactic sugar?

Comment: I found this: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6864. Not sure if it was ever resolved.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? `DateTime.now...Float::INFINITY` works fine in Rails 5.0.0.1.

Comment: Oh, I'm using `4.2.5`

Comment: @MuradYusufov: it works without rails even. In plain IRB 2.3.1 console.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev that's true, yeah, I just forgot to `require 'date'` at first. This raises next question: what version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ruby 2.2.4

Comment: And yes, it is REALLY WEIRD that when I run `rails c` `DateTime.now...Float::INFINITY` breaks, and yet in pry, `DateTime.now...Float::INFINITY` is fine. Strange strange magic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that what you want to do is a correct way of solving such issue.

What I would suggest instead, is to simply override the `end_date` method in model:

```
def end_date
  super == Float::INFINITY ? DateTime::Infinity.new : super
end
```

This basically says if `end_date` in db is `Float::INFINITY` return `DateTime::Infinity.new` as `end_date`, otherwise return what's in database.

Comment: @fatuhoku Ok, let me know if that worked. Also, it is rally strange that `DateTime.now...Float::INFINITY` does not work for you as is..

Answer (score 1):

Ruby 2.6 introduces [endless range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Range.html#class-Range-label-Endless+Ranges), which can be used in this manner, for example:

```
(DateTime.now..)
(DateTime.now...)
```

This provides a new approach to answering this question. Hope it's useful for someone!